# I need to calculate day sale ,MTD and YTD sale for each item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find MTD (Month to date) and YTD (Year to Date) sales value for each item. And, I have filter to entire data on which I need to find the sales report. Based on that date it should find the MTD and YTD sales. it should group the item by barcode. Example: in my filter if i enter: 21th of August , I should find that day sales and MTD,YTD.

It is working fine with current date, but if i entire any date other than current date then there is difference in MTD and YTD

```
SELECT Barcode,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1) THEN sales_amount ELSE 0 END) AS day_1,
       SUM(CASE
                WHEN MONTH(date) = (MONTH(GETDATE() - 1))
                 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE() - 1) THENsales_amount
                ELSE 0
           END) AS month_t,
       SUM(CASE
                WHEN MONTH(date) = (MONTH(GETDATE() - 1))
                 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE() - 1) - 1 THEN GL_TOTALTTC
                ELSE 0
           END) AS lastyear_tm,
FROM sale
WHERE type = 'FFO'
  AND store = 'AE001A'
  AND (DATE = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
    OR ((MONTH(date) = (MONTH(GETDATE() - 1))
     AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE() - 1))
     OR (MONTH(date) = (MONTH(GETDATE() - 1))
     AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE() - 1) - 1)))
GROUP BY barcode;
```

Comment: Please explain what acronyms mean, even if they seem self explanatory to you. I don't know what MTD or YTD means.

Comment: MTD -  sales of that item on the entire month ,YTD is last year same month sale

Comment: share your table schema and some input data with case on which your above mentioned query fails, if didn't get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select bar_code,
       sum(case when date >= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()) then sales_amount end) as yesterday,
       sum(case when month(date) = month(getdate()) and year(date) = year(getdate()) then sales_amount end) as mtd,
       sum(case when year(date) = year(getdate()) then sales_amount end) as ytd
from sale
where type = 'FFO' and store = 'AE001A' 
group by barcode;
```

Comment: this will not always ,yesterday and current month ..                                     
 sum(case when date >= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()) then sales_amount end) as yesterday.... this is to get current month,year and yesterday

Comment: @Angel . . . This does assume that you don't have future data in the table.